# xs:boolean " false" with space

Tags: xml, boolean

I have xml with an element  belonging to simple type "TFIndicator" which has a boolean restriction:

```
<xs:simpleType name="TFIndicator">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation source="Name" xml:lang="EN">
            TFIndicator
        </xs:documentation>
        <xs:documentation source="Definition" xml:lang="EN">
            A flag indicating a True or False value.
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:boolean"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

According to xs:boolean definition:

> "The value space of xsd:boolean is true and false. Its lexical space
>   accepts true, false, and also 1 (for true) and 0 (for false)."

I'm validating an xml (with XMLSpy and and IBM integrated XML validator) with this element:

```
<HasData> false</HasData> (notice the space)
```

Apparently both validators return that this is a valid xml.

Is this behaviour correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is standard.

From the [boolean datatype definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#boolean) :

> The boolean datatype and all datatypes derived from it by restriction have the following ·constraining facets· with fixed values; these facets must not be changed from the values shown:
>
> whiteSpace = collapse (fixed)

And from the [whitespace facet definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#rf-whiteSpace) :

> collapse
>
> After the processing implied by replace, contiguous sequences of #x20's are collapsed to a single #x20, and **any #x20 at the start or end of the string is then removed.**

Note that this is true of every simple type other than `xs:string`, which default whitespace facet is `preserve` and can be configured.

Elements' content are normalized at the beginning of the validation process, and [whitespace normalization](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-xmlschema11-1-20120405/structures.html#sec-wsnormalization) according to the whitespace facet is one part of that process. Comment removal is another one, so for instance `<tag> <!----> 1 <!----> </tag>` also is a valid `xs:integer` (and `xs:boolean`).